# Calculus ll, I would really appreciate any help checking how I did please

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to solve this calculus ll exercise and I have been having problems, I wanted to know if you can examine it and tell me what you think, Is it wrong? Is it right?, What am I doing wrong?, How you would do it?, anything helps. Hope you can help and thank you very much in advance

Here is part 1.A of my question:

[image: 1. Using Integration: (a) the formula for calculating the area from the inner region to the ellipse \frac{x\power{2}|a\power{2}}+ \frac{y\power{2}|b\power{2}} =]

Here is what I did:
[image: graphic]
[image: Part 1.a]

Here is part 1.B of my question:
[image: 1. Using Integration:(b) the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region of part (a) around the x-axis.]

Here is what I did:
[image: Part 1.b]

Please tell me how I did, and I just wanted to say thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Both are correct. For the second one, the volume of ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} \leq 1$ is given by $\frac{4 \pi}{3} abc$ and here $c = b$ so that validates your answer. There is a typo in the end, not sure where $u^3$ came from.

Comment: u^3 to my knowledge is the cubic and square units in integrals, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: if you are using that to show volume is $u^3$ then that's fine.

Comment: Do you think it's unnecessary? Or do you know a better way to represent that?

Comment: Yes I think it is unnecessary and I have not seen it being a norm to explicitly mention it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll remember for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are both correct. For the first question, it is easier to find the area by using change of variables and polar coordinates.

The region is $ ~ \displaystyle \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \leq 1$

We use $x = a r \cos\theta, y = b r \sin\theta$ and the region transforms to,

$r \leq 1$ which is a unit circle in polar coordinates.

Jacobian of transformation is $|J| = ab r$

So the integral becomes,

$ \displaystyle A = \iint_{\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \leq 1} dA = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 ab ~ r ~ dr ~ d\theta$

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback I really appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome!